# Adding to opportunity different products from different pricebooks

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, pricebook, product

I am trying to figure it out how can I implement this idea,
I saw that this question already been asked but I haven't found an answer for that.

Does someone maybe knows what are the options available? 
.
.
.

[I want to rephrase my question,
Let's say I have 2 users in the ORG and they can see all products in it,
If I have an opportunity in my system, I want that each user will be able to add product line item to the opportunity BUT only from the SET of products he is working with. I thought to set different pricebooks for different users but then realized that only one pricebook is permitted in an opportunity]

Thanks.

Comment: Each opportunity can have only one price book. My idea that I nearly implemented for a project a few years back was to create a new real price book for each opportunity (you can have unlimited price books), and add products to the price book via Visualforce pages.

Comment: @sfdcfox I want to develop similar functionality. Since you have already implemented, could you please let me know if there were any challenges you faced with suggested approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Opportunity may have only one pricebook. You can see this by looking at the [SFDC Object Reference for Opportunity](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm#topic-title) - there is a field called `Pricebook2Id`

As you no doubt have learned, each `OpportunityLineItem` references a `PriceBookEntry` via its `PricebookEntryId` field and SFDC enforces that those PriceBookEntries must belong to the Opportunity's `Pricebook2`

So, how to work around this?

**Option 1** - Just use the Standard Pricebook wherein all products/prices must reside

**Option 2** - Use your own custom uber-pricebook(s) - maybe your application permits logical but still distinct super-pricebooks - maybe one for Commercial versus Federal pricing as no Opportunity would have both Commercial and Federal SKUs

**Option 3** @sfdcfox has a suggestion in his comment to your OP

Note that other parts of SFDC use PricebookEntries (PriceBook2Id) too so if you are using those aspects of SFDC, consideration their ramifcations:

- `Orderitem` (`Order`)
- `QuoteLineItem` (`Quote`)
- `ContractLineItem` (`ServiceContract`)